# Invalid bucket name in Google Cloud Storage when backup Google App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a few python applications running in Google App Engine, and using datastore as storage.

I'm referring to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#backing_up_data

> When you choose Cloud Storage, you are prompted for the bucket name
>   where the backups are to be stored, in the format /my_bucket_name. You
>   can optionally specify the bucket name suffixed with a directory
>   structure (e.g., /bucket_name/backups/backup1): If those folders don't
>   already exist, they will be created. Note: In older versions of App
>   Engine, users were required to use the format /gs/bucket_name. While
>   the prefix /gs/ will continue to work, it is no longer required.

Hence, I try to supply `/my_bucket_name` as Google Cloud Storage bucket name.

[image]

However, when I click on **Backup Entities**, I get error

```
Unsupported filesystem: my_bucket_name
```

[image]

---

I try another name `/gs/bucket_name`

[image]

I get

```
Bucket "bucket_name" not accessible
```

[image]

I was wondering, how can I provide a valid bucket name for Google Cloud Storage, in order to backup my datastore?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem I solved as follows:

I add to my bucket permissions this entry: *MyAPPiD*@appspot.gserviceaccount.com with write access.

I entered the name of my bucket **without** the "/" before, even if it is not what is stated in the documentation. In your example, it would simply write **my_bucket_name**.

The copy was successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a bucket in your project before trying to perform the backup.
To create a bucket, go to Storage menu and select Browser option.